# Setting up a wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I downloaded a WordPress website and copied it to a folder on localhost.

However the it's asking me for a database name which is WordPress as I created a database in phpmyadmin.

Then it asks for User Name : no matter what i type it does not accept it, the same goes for Password: and Database Host Name. I have no password on phpmyadmin i login as root and there is no password.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: did you try username: root pw: root ?

Comment: and you did username: root and left pw empty?

Comment: What webserver software are you running? e.g. XAMPP, WAMP, etc?

Comment: What does the entries in the table db and user of the database mysql look like? Are the db and user values what you expect? Are the right privileges 'Y'?

Comment: Have you checked settings at `/wp-config.php` match those at phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really sure what your username and password are and still not working, you should download again   wordpress... I've setup a few times Wordpress locally and I found it very simple. (Change directory name, different database name and so on).